# Cannot install MYSQL on Fedora - Curl error TIMEOUT on repo.mysql.com

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

I am trying to install MySQL 8.0 Community Edition on Fedora 34. I installed the repo rom from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

After running `sudo dnf install mysql-community-server` I am getting the below error output:

```
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                       0.0  B/s |   0  B     12:42    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30020 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/c55e90c7ab0dc694323139988d5868a381c441ff-primary.xml.gz [Resolving timed out after 30096 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/c55e90c7ab0dc694323139988d5868a381c441ff-primary.xml.gz [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/c55e90c7ab0dc694323139988d5868a381c441ff-primary.xml.gz [Resolving timed out after 30001 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30001 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/5920395724110a6f03637c4f6187bfa801f8a70b-filelists.xml.gz [Resolving timed out after 30096 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30004 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql80-community': Yum repo downloading error: Downloading error(s): repodata/c55e90c7ab0dc694323139988d5868a381c441ff-primary.xml.gz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success; repodata/5920395724110a6f03637c4f6187bfa801f8a70b-filelists.xml.gz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success
MySQL Connectors Community                                                                       0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:39    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-connectors-community':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30026 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30001 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30023 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30006 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-connectors-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Tools Community                                                                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:38    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-tools-community':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30053 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30007 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30101 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-tools-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Tools Preview                                                                              0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:17    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-tools-preview':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30004 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30027 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30031 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-tools-preview': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL 8.0 Community Server - Source                                                                                                    0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:28    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community-source':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30125 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql80-community-source': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Connectors Community - Source                                                                                                    0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:44    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-connectors-community-source':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30002 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-connectors-community-source': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Tools Community - Source                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:45    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-tools-community-source':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30029 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30084 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30001 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-tools-community-source': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Tools Preview - Source                                                                                                           0.0  B/s |   0  B     08:36    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-tools-preview-source':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30007 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 32320 milliseconds]
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/34/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml [Resolving timed out after 30001 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-tools-preview-source': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: mysql80-community, mysql-connectors-community, mysql-tools-community, mysql-tools-preview, mysql80-community-source, mysql-connectors-community-source, mysql-tools-community-source, mysql-tools-preview-source
Last metadata expiration check: 0:31:20 ago on Sunday 11 July 2021 10:46:17 AM.
No match for argument: mysql-community-server
Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-community-server
[root@fedora ~]#
```

Installed Repo Package:

```
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$ dnf list installed | grep mysql
mysql80-community-release.noarch                  fc34-1                               @@commandline         
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$
```

RepoList:

```
[rajiv@fedora ~]$ sudo dnf repolist
[sudo] password for rajiv: 
repo id                                                                         repo name
fedora                                                                          Fedora 34 - x86_64
fedora-cisco-openh264                                                           Fedora 34 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
fedora-modular                                                                  Fedora Modular 34 - x86_64
google-chrome                                                                   google-chrome
mysql-connectors-community                                                      MySQL Connectors Community
mysql-connectors-community-source                                               MySQL Connectors Community - Source
mysql-tools-community                                                           MySQL Tools Community
mysql-tools-community-source                                                    MySQL Tools Community - Source
mysql-tools-preview                                                             MySQL Tools Preview
mysql-tools-preview-source                                                      MySQL Tools Preview - Source
mysql80-community                                                               MySQL 8.0 Community Server
mysql80-community-source                                                        MySQL 8.0 Community Server - Source
updates                                                                         Fedora 34 - x86_64 - Updates
updates-modular                                                                 Fedora Modular 34 - x86_64 - Updates
```

Contents of Repo:

```
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$ pwd
/etc/yum.repos.d
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$ ls 
_copr_phracek-PyCharm.repo  fedora.repo                  fedora-updates-testing-modular.repo  mysql-community.repo                  rpmfusion-nonfree-steam.repo
fedora-cisco-openh264.repo  fedora-updates-modular.repo  fedora-updates-testing.repo          mysql-community-source.repo
fedora-modular.repo         fedora-updates.repo          google-chrome.repo                   rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver.repo
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$ tac mysql-community.repo 

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/$releasever/$basearch/
name=MySQL Tools Preview
[mysql-tools-preview]

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/$releasever/$basearch/
name=MySQL Tools Community
[mysql-tools-community]

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/$releasever/$basearch/
name=MySQL Connectors Community
[mysql-connectors-community]

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/$releasever/$basearch/
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
[mysql80-community]
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$ tac mysql-community-source.repo 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/fc/$releasever/SRPMS
name=MySQL Tools Preview - Source
[mysql-tools-preview-source]

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/$releasever/SRPMS
name=MySQL Tools Community - Source
[mysql-tools-community-source]

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/$releasever/SRPMS
name=MySQL Connectors Community - Source
[mysql-connectors-community-source]

gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/$releasever/SRPMS
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server - Source
[mysql80-community-source]
[rajiv@fedora yum.repos.d]$
```

I tried reinstalling the repo package, but it still the same issue. Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of troubleshooting, following steps has enabled to get the installation right: -

Installation Steps: [Component]-[FileNameReference]

1. Configuration - mysql-community-common
2. Client Plugins - mysql-community-client
3. Shared Library - mysql-community-libs
4. Development Libraries - mysql-community-devel
5. Client Utilties - mysql-community-client
6. MySQL Server - mysql-community-server
7. Workbench - mysql-community-workbench